# Hibernate for ontologies?

Tags: java, hibernate, sparql, owl, ontology

does anybody know of a tool capable of doing for OWL ontologies what Hibernate does for relational databases, that is, from my point of view, abstract away the need to manually code SQL queries to read/write Java objects from/to relational databases and manage the consistency of in-memory objects and their serialized form on the DB.

In the case of OWL ontologies, such a tool could, among other things, generate SPARQL queries to read (and write?) data from an RDF store (like Jena) and create the corresponding Java objects.

Many Thanks :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ORMs for RDF data, written in Java, Python, Ruby. Take a look here for an overview: http://semanticweb.org/wiki/Tripresso

Comment: Thanks, good source of information. See also http://code.google.com/p/jenabean/.

Answer (score 1):

Hope [it](https://web.archive.org/web/20130319143534/http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/1392/oop-mapping-orm-solutions-for-java)'ll be helpful. There is a list of OOP mapping / ORM solutions for Java.